# Why should we help people?

Tags: karma, dharma, moksha, daana, artha

If the goal for everyone is to go beyond worldly happiness and sadness, and sadness can help nudge people towards vairagya why should we help people materially?

Comment: Service is satva gun of maya, which brings us closer to god(This is present everywhere in buddha teachings)

Comment: @Aditya Dwivedi it is helpful for us, sure but isn't it kinda selfish

Comment: And why would brahmajnanis still help people

Comment: I don't know any brahmajnani, but it is clearly selfish to not help someone even if you know they need it, and It is not selfish to help due to compassion

Comment: Your assumptions are incorrect. Sadness doesn't always lead to vairagya. Helping is one of core habits (Daan) because it helps in disconnecting with worldly pleasures like money or food or even gyaan hence helps in developing vairagya. Vairagya doesn't mean sadness, but neither sadness nor happiness.